# Cocoa graphical glitches

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, autolayout, appkit

I added a Safari tab-like system to my Cocoa application and since, I got some serious graphical glitches. I implemented the tab system in Auto Layout, simply with buttons on a horizontal stack view with another tabless tab view, nothing special.

I started with something looking like this:

[image: Original]

to issues like blank labels and the search field color and font are weird.

[image]

There are no errors in the console, just graphical glitches. The constraints looks okay, the keyboard and mouse events are working well as well, nothing seems to be broken other than the render.

The "Debug View Hierarchy" does not seems to have the same issue than in Runtime:

[image]

I looked around for similar graphical glitches, but could not found anything.

My app is in Swift 4.0, I am using the last stable XCode and OS X version.

I don't know where to look. I am looking for some tips to help me debug this! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running it on 10.12?  Do you have an older graphics card?  Is this using NSCollectionView?  We're kind of limited, without seeing some source code.

Comment: In my experience, in some set-ups, the presence/absence of layers can cause drawing issues like this; try making your window's content-view layer-backed, and see if this improves matters. (You can make a view layer-backed in interface builder, via the *View Effects* inspector: select the view, open this inspector, and check the relevant checkbox in the *Core Animation Layer* section.)

Comment: @Ssswift Sorry for the lacks of details, I can't put copyrighted code and was unable to reproduce in a small application example.

Comment: @paul-patterson Thank you for the suggestion. It gaves me a slightly different result were the text was written in a kind of shadow effect, while the same gray background is showing over transparent the labels in the info header. I found the solution and I am going to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was because I had a Visual Effect View with the "Vibrant Dark" effect, then the tab view were created from a custom view controller which was inheriting the Aqua apparence by default. The mix of the two apparences seems to be the cause of the graphical issues and it explained why default apparence inheritance was not an issue until I implemented my tab system which broke the main view into a separated view controller. Such a weird Cocoa display issue...